# ¿Como remover comillas de un query POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Intento realizar una consulta que por me dio de un `SELECT` dentro de un `IN` me muestre la información que en cuyo requerimiento necesito; se que el problema que puedo tener es porque el campo dinámico para los `IN` es un `VARCHAR` (24,34), y en la tabla principal los `id` son `INTEGER`, entonces ¿como podría remover esas comillas para simular que es una especie de "arreglo" con números enteros?

**SQL**

```
SELECT public.tb_encuesta.enc_nombre
FROM public.tb_encuesta
WHERE public.tb_encuesta.enc_id IN (
                                     SELECT CAST (per_enc_id AS integer)// Este es el campo que contiene los valores 
                                     FROM public.tb_periodo
                                     WHERE per_estado = true
                                     ORDER BY per_id DESC
                                     LIMIT 1
      )
```

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "24,34"

Agradecería el interés

Comment: de que tipo de dato es `per_enc_id `???

Comment: varchar, este es quien contiene la cadena de valores.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo así: **`... IN (SELECT string_to_array(per_enc_id  ',')::int[]) FROM ...`** [Ver aquí la documentación de `string_to_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)

Comment: =cast((select per_enc_id ) as integer)

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano gracias por tu interes, intente realizar tu codigo y me muestra el sgte error, syntax error at or near ":"

Comment: Me faltó una coma, revisa la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Tendrías que hacer el uso de `split_part` para que te pueda dar los valores separados, pero deberías de estar seguro que solo tienes dos valores ademas de tenerlos en el orden correcto.

La función `split_part` de PostgreSQL se usa para dividir una cadena dada(1<sup>er</sup> parametro) en base a un delimitador(2<sup>do</sup> parametro) y seleccionar el campo deseado de la cadena(3<sup>er</sup> parametro), comienza desde la izquierda de la cadena.

Por ejemplo teniendo `per_enc_id="24,34"`:

```
SELECT CAST (split_part(per_enc_id,',',1) AS integer)
FROM public.tb_periodo
WHERE per_estado = true
ORDER BY per_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Suponiendo que toda la consulta va bien este deberia de resultar: 24.

En caso de querer el segundo elemento del split cambiamos `split_part(per_enc_id,',',2)`.

En caso de necesitar todos los elementos de la cadena, necesariamente deberias de saber cuantos existen, en tu caso quizás siempre serán dos separados por una sola coma entonces:

```
SELECT CAST (split_part(per_enc_id,',',1) AS integer) as per_id, CAST (split_part(per_enc_id,',',2) AS integer) as enc_id
FROM public.tb_periodo
WHERE per_estado = true
ORDER BY per_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Los `as per_id` y `as enc_id` depende de ti si los deseas o no.

Comment: men la verdad me ha funcionado pero digamos que en este caso necesito todos los elementos, como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta si deseas los dos elementos

Answer (score 0):

prueba esto:

```
SELECT public.tb_encuesta.enc_nombre
FROM public.tb_encuesta
WHERE public.tb_encuesta.enc_id IN (
                                     SELECT CONVERT(per_enc_id,INT) // Este es el campo que contiene los valores 
                                     FROM public.tb_periodo
                                     WHERE per_estado = true
                                     ORDER BY per_id DESC
                                     LIMIT 1
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar: [`string_to_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html). Es una función que:

> Divide la cadena en elementos de matriz utilizando el delimitador
>   suministrado y la cadena nula opcional.

Por ejemplo:

```
string_to_array(valor,separador
SELECT public.tb_encuesta.enc_nombre
FROM public.tb_encuesta
WHERE public.tb_encuesta.enc_id IN (
                                     SELECT string_to_array(per_enc_id,',')::int[] 
                                     FROM public.tb_periodo
                                     WHERE per_estado = true
                                     ORDER BY per_id DESC
                                     LIMIT 1
      )
```